# Error while installing Mvc Scaffolding package using Package Manager Consoler in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

I am new for using Package Manager Console. I need to install `Autofac.Mvc3` and  `MvcScaffolding` packages. I tried to install using Package Manager Console by running the below commands.

```
PM> Install-Package Autofac.Mvc3
```

But I got the below error.

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Autofac (≥ 2.6.3.862)'.
>   Install-Package : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred        on a send.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Autofac.Mvc3
>   + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

And while installing `MvcScaffolding`:

```
PM> Install-Package MvcScaffolding
```

It throws the this error.

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding'.
>   Install-Package : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  MvcScaffolding
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :    NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I do have some pre-installed dll's in 'packages' folder while creating a MVC4 application in VS2012 but it does not contain MvcScaffolding/ Autofac.

Please tell must I install those in 'packages' folder or will it get install by running the above commands.

Please help.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do these packages connect to a database? I had a similar message last week and it was due to my connection string being wrong!

Comment: No. These packages not connect to database. And now this error got resolved for me. I wonder how it got resolved. I tried running those commands again. Now it installed properly and my web.config also changed according to that!. I followed the below link. It helped me a bit.[Nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

Answer (score 0):

This error got resolved for me. I wonder how it got resolved. I tried running those commands again. Now it installed properly and my web.config also changed according to that!. I followed this [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console). It helped me much.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work well on VS 2012

Also does it work well with reference models, and FK relationships on your models for CRUD?